# setting up nginx with django and php on aws

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, django

I am trying to set up nginx for django app and php on AWS / Linux AMI. Nginx has already been configured to work for multiple django apps simultaneously and all works fine.

Now I need to include the third party solution based on php. This should work on separate url /dash/.

I went through many tutorials and "stack" answers, but none worked for me.

I have already installed php and php-fpm. I modified config file at /etc/php-fpm-5.5.d/www.conf and tried using both socket and TCP/IP:

`listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`

and also

`listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock`

After restarting php-fpm service I checked that the socket has really been created. Then I modified nginx accordingly:

```
location ~ /dash/$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I created the test.php file to test php and also placed the third party solution to the /usr/share/nginx/html/. When I try to visit https://DOMAIN/dash/ I got 404 error (or I got blank page if I remove `try_files` setting). However, when I try to visit https://DOMAIN/dash/index.php or https://DOMAIN/test.php, the browser offers me a file to download - the actual index.php file I expected to produce the html for me. I get the same result using wget.

`service php-fpm status` claims `php-fpm-5.5 (pid 12345) is running...` so I supposed the php files should be processed.

I already tried to change php-fpm config by changing attributes `listen.owner` and `list.group` as well as `user` and `group` to `nobody`, `ec2-user` or `nginx` but I still get the same 404.

I have already tried the parameter
`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME ...`
but as I was not sure what exactly should be here I removed it. I suppose now we use the default from the `fastcgi_param` file: 
`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;`

If you see some obvious mistake or something I overlook, please let me know. I apologize for the wrong terminology if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` needs to process URIs that end with `.php`. If your configuration is downloading your PHP files, you probably already have the `root` set correctly.

Many installations have a suitable value for `SCRIPT_NAME` within the included `fastcgi_params` file, but the example below shows it stated explicitly (just in case).

For example:

```
root ...;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
```

The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are not required in this case. Always place `fastcgi_param` statements **after** the `include` statement, otherwise your directives may be silently overridden.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I have changed the location to process .php files but in this case the browser does not offer the files to be downloaded. Now I get 500 when I go to the /dash/index.php but it is the problem of the script itself, I believe.

Comment: I checked the test.php and it works, so the third party solution is not working actually. Thank you once again.